# Why is $\frac{f}{\|f\|}$ a submersion when this matrix has rank $k$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

A paper I'm reading defines the following $\left(\frac{(k-1)k}{2}+1\right)\times n$ matrix:

\begin{align*}
\Omega_f(x) := 
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{1,2}(x)\\ 
\vdots \\ 
\omega_{i,j}(x) \\
\vdots \\
\omega_{k-1,k}(x) \\
x_1, \ldots, x_n
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

where $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$, $f = (P_1,\ldots,P_k)$ and $\omega_{i,j} = P_i(x)\nabla P_j(x) - P_j(x)\nabla P_i(x)$. 
It is then stated that $\operatorname{rank} \Omega_f(x) = k$ is equivalent to saying that $\frac{f}{\|f\|}$ is a submersion. I've tried to work out why this is the case, and all I've come up with is that $\frac{\omega_{i,j}(x)}{P_i^2(x) + P_j^2(x)} = \nabla\chi(x)$ if $\chi(x) = \arctan\left(\frac{P_j(x)}{P_i(x)}\right)$.

I assume it has something to do with some parametrization of the sphere by angles, but I can't see how to get from $\Omega_f$ to $J(\frac{f}{\|f\|})$ or back.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: is $p=k$ and $m=n$?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the $ij$ entry of the Jacobian of $f/\|f\|$ is $$\frac{1}{\|f\|^3}\langle f,((\omega_{1i})_j,\ldots,(\omega_{ki})_j)\rangle,$$ where $(\omega_{li})_j$ is the $j$-th component of $\omega_{li}$.

Comment: @A.Bellmunt Yes, sorry. Changed now.